# Are there proteins with permanently bound magnesium?

Tags: biochemistry

Do you know something about the existence of a magnesium containing protein/enzyme in which magnesium is coordinated in the structure and the structure is stable? (like iron in haemoglobin or zinc in zinc fingers)

Comment: Chlorophyll? This is not hard to find :) https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Magnesium_in_biology&section=9#Biological_chemistry

Comment: @gilleain Chlorophyll isn't a protein.

Comment: @DavePhD : Right, I was thinking of the cofactor since OP mentioned haemoglobin but regardless - it's not exactly a rare metal to find in proteins.

Answer (score 8):

From the look of things you may actually be referring to a lot of different proteins, however I managed to
grab two that I found fascinating:

1. **Enolase**

A glycolytic enzyme which catalyzes the reversible dehydration of 2-phosphoglycerate to phosphoenolpyruvate:

[image: A] [image: B]

*Credits: Lehninger Principles of Biochemistry page 213 ("Enzymes")*

- In the enzyme active site, 2-phosphoglycerate undergoes strong ionic interactions with two bound Mg2+ ions causing the resulting intermediate to be easily abstracted.

---

2. GTPase specifically  **ARF1** (ARF for ADP-ribosylation factor). These are important in priming phase in the formation of Clathrin-coated vesicles (CCVs).

   - Clathrin itself is  a protein that forms a polyhedral framework around vesicles that transport TM, GPIlinked, and secreted proteins from the Golgi to the plasma
     membrane.

X-ray structures of ARF1.GDP and ARF1.GTP, were determined by Dagmar Ringe and by Jonathan Goldberg:

[image]

*Credits Voet and Voet Biochemistry 4th ed page 435 ("Membrane Assembly and Protein Targeting")*

*X-ray structures of (a) ARF1.GDP (left) and (b)ARF1.GMPPNP (right) (GMPPNP is a nonhydrolyzable GTP analog in which the O atom linking GTP’s beta- and gamma-phosphorus atoms is replaced by an NH group.)*

*The bound nucleotides are drawn in stick form in white with their phosphorus atoms magenta and their bound **$\ce{Mg^2+}$** ions shown as **lavender spheres**.*

*In ARF1.GDP, the protein’s N-terminal helix (red) together with its
covalently linked myristoyl group (not present in the X-ray structures) are bound in a shallow hydrophobic groove on the
surface of the protein formed in part by the residues of loop gamma 3.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As far as I am concerned, enolase or other glicolytic enzymes don't have prosthetic groups with magnesium, so the metal in there is just a cofactor, being much of an activator. However, I have never heard about ARF1 and I think that this is the example I'm looking for. Thank you for the hint :)

Comment: The metal is actually bound to the enzyme enolase :) Read more: Plant Biochemistry J Bonner page 216 > Enolase contains a bound magnesium ion as an essential component...

Comment: Anytime! glad I could help :)